# Testing two adjacent lines

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file with my lines and I want to compare lines that are one after the other to test if they are the same except for the last column. For example:

```
example/example 321
example/example 456
otherexample/otherexample 321
```

In this case, I want the program to simply return:

```
example/example
```

As the first column matches, but the second column is different. What is the best way to do this using Unix tools? So far I have tried *awk* but have had little success. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# sample data
$ cat input.txt
example/example 321
example/example 456
example/example 789
otherexample/otherexample 321
abc
otherexample/otherexample 321

$ awk 'x==$1{print $1; while(getline){if(x!=$1)break}}{x=$1}' input.txt
example/example
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Works like a charm. Though, I'm very new to awk and I'm not sure that I fully understand the inner workings of this code yet, so I have a few questions:
1. What is the difference between the '=='and '=' sign. I know that in many languages one sets a variable and the other tests equivalency, is that the same with awk?
2. Why is print $1; before the while loop instead of at the end?
Thanks very much!

Comment: `==` has the same meaning as in `C++`. You can put `print $1` after the `while...loop`.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
## In first line, get path and init counter of consecutive paths.
FNR == 1 { 
    path = $1
    repeats = 1 
    next
}

FNR > 1 { 
    ## If current path is same as previous one, increment counter.
    if ( path == $1 ) { 
        ++repeats;
    }   
    ## Else, there is new path, so print previous and init counter.
    else {
        print_repeated_path( repeats, path )
        path = $1
        repeats = 0 
    }   
}

END {
    print_repeated_path( repeats, path )
}

function print_repeated_path(r, path) {
    if ( r > 1 ) { 
        printf "%s\n", path
    }   
}
```

Content of `infile`:

```
example/example 321
example/example 456
otherexample/otherexample 321
other/example 456
other/example 678
other/example 123
otherexample/otherexample 321
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

With following result:

```
example/example
other/example
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort -u temp.txt|awk '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a){if(a[i]>1)print i;}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 file | sort | uniq -d
```

or this:

```
 sort file | sed '$!N;/^\(\S*\) .*\n\1.*/!D;bb;:a;$!N;:b;s//\1/;ta;P;D'
```